# Image on Navigation Bar Back Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In our application I use Left and right button on navigation bar.
I want a image on back (left)button.If i use segment for that then 
necessary to define a action for back button.
Please advice me for any method.

Comment: You have asked 23 questions and not once marked an answer as "accepted" (the green check mark next to an answer). Doing so will encourage more people to answer your questions. It's a way of giving credit and thanking those who have helped you.

Comment: lol, and yet... still no accepted answer in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you use a Bar Button item you can go to Bar Button Item Attributes in Interface Builder and there should an Image option you can select.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by subclassing UINavigationBar, then create a method like this :

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonWithImage:(NSString *)imageName target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     UIImage *titleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
     [button setImage:titleImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [button sizeToFit];
     UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    return item;
}
```

And then add it to your navigation bar like this :

```
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[TFNavigationBar barButtonWithImage:@"rp_settings.png" target:self action:@selector(showSettings)]];
```

p.s: I prefer to use singletons, that's why that it is.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way we found to replace the back button with our own goes like this.

1. Add a back button in the nib file outside your view. customize it as you wish.
2. connect it as an IBOutlet. Let's call it btnBack.
3. in ViewDidLoad do this:

   ```
   UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
   [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:back animated:YES];
   ```
4. connect an action to your backBtn like this:

   ```
   - (IBAction)Back:(id)sender {
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
   ```

And thats it you got yourself a customized back button :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply replace your back button with an image through out your app..

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button"]];
```

Or for specific navigation bars specify your navBar instead of '[UINavigationBar appearance]'. This works perfectly.